# How to format a java.sql.Timestamp(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S) to a date(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Tags: java, date, timestamp, simpledateformat, netbeans-7.1

Well, I'm having a detail using a `Date`, because I'm getting an Object from my DataBase and in the variable "fecha" (date) from that same object I'm getting a `java.sql.Timestamp`, so the formatt is with miliseconds, but i don't want the miliseconds to appear. So i need to formatt the date that I'm receiving from my DB to a new date that doesn't have miliseconds.

This is the object Factura:

```
public class Factura  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private FacturaId id;
 ...
 private boolean activo;
 private Date fecha;
}
```

In the xml that is mapped to the DB I have this code for that variable "fecha":

```
<property name="fecha" type="timestamp">
  <column length="19" name="fecha" not-null="true"/>
</property>
```

In the Database that column is `fecha DATETIME`.

And when I get an object `Factura` from my DB I'm getting this kind of date `2013-10-10 10:49:29.0` but I want it without the `.0` (miliseconds).

I've tried this (`factura` is the `Factura` object):

```
try {
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date fechaNueva = null;
   String fechaStr = factura.getFecha().toString();
   int tamaño = fechaStr.length()-2;
   fechaStr = fechaStr.substring(0, tamaño); //I get a string without the miliseconds
   fechaNueva = format.parse(fechaStr);
} catch(ParseException ex) {
   ...
}
```

But `fechaNueva` is giving me `Thu Oct 10 10:49:29 CDT 2013` and I only want `2013-10-10 10:49:29`, can you help me, please?

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You do not need to use substring at all since your `format` doesn't hold that info.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String fechaStr = "2013-10-10 10:49:29.10000";  
Date fechaNueva = format.parse(fechaStr);

System.out.println(format.format(fechaNueva)); // Prints 2013-10-10 10:49:29
```

Comment: Thanks, bug I forget to say that i want to put that new fecha `fechaNueva` to the same object... something like this: 

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String fechaStr = "2013-10-10 10:49:29.10000";  
Date fechaNueva = format.parse(fechaStr);
factura.setFecha(fechaNueva);`

But just with `Date fechaNueva = format.parse(fechaStr);` I got the wrong format `Thu Oct 10 10:49:29 CDT 2013` that i dont want...

Comment: @user2284257 No, not wrong format. It just prints by default (check the toString method of Date class) that way and of course uses your local timezone as you didn't specify a locale. You need to format it the way you want it to print as I did inside the print statement. That is not a problem because no matter how you format for your printing needs, the value of fechaNueva is still the same.

Comment: Ok, something like `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);` ? I have tried that `Locale.ENGLISH` but nothing. Do you know what `Locale` could help me? or how to formatt that `date` to have the formatt i want? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2284257 Locale is for TimeZone, not for formatting. format method of SimpleDateFormat is what you need as I stated before and in my print statement. If you tried the code I provided, you should see the correct output as you stated in your question: 2013-10-10 10:49:29

Comment: Yes, that's right, as a `String` is correct, but how I put that correct format `2013-10-10 10:49:29` to my object `Factura` as a `Date`? this is the problem: `factura.setFecha(fechaNueva);`, what i have to do to `fechaNueva` to have it formatted to `2013-10-10 10:49:29`?

Comment: It's because i use that `Factura` object in a `TableModel`, so its printing at the column `fecha` this: `Thu Oct 10 10:49:29 CDT 2013`

Comment: I think you are having problem understanding the concept. You are saving the correct value when you do setFecha. When you are printing it in your TableModel, print it using the format you want. You can create other simple date formats for your printing needs. Just don't do System.out.print(fechaNueva) or fechaNueva.toString(). You need to format it before you print.

Answer (score 3):

## A date-time object is not a String

The java.sql.Timestamp class has no format. Its toString method *generates* a String with a format.

Do not conflate a date-time object with a String that may represent its value. A date-time object can parse strings and generate strings but is not itself a string.

## java.time

First convert from the troubled old legacy date-time classes to java.time classes. Use the new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = mySqlDate.toInstant() ;
```

Lose the fraction of a second you don't want.

```
instant = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

Assign the time zone to adjust from UTC used by Instant.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Generate a String close to your desired output. Replace its `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ;
String output = zdt.format( f ).replace( "T" , " " );
```