# Saving a timestamp value from a given string value

Tags: java, timestamp

I am having a string value in format "Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 UTC 1996";
. I want this value to be converted into a timestamp field in "30-APR-96 05:30:00.000000000 AM"

What i tried here is

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(str);
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date getTime());
SimpleDateFormat fo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS a");
fo.format(ts);
//When i try here Timestamp.valueOf(fo.format(ts));
```

I am getting an exception Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.ffffff]

In DB when i see i have the type as Timestamp and values are stored in  "30-APR-96 05:30:00.000000000 AM"

Comment: I see that the  "30-APR-96 05:30:00.00000000 AM" has 8 ending zero's while the error says [.ffffff] which is 6. Maybe it cannot interpret that?

Comment: May be in writing i missed zero but there are 9 zeros

Comment: `Timestamp.valueOf()` requires a string in the format of `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...]` and nothing else.

Comment: So what could be possible solution for it?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: A `Timestamp` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. Also timestamps are not stored in the database in the format you mention. They are only displayed that way when you retrieve them. Does this answer your question? [Timestamp comes with .0 at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545196/timestamp-comes-with-0-at-the-end). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544067/how-to-format-a-java-sql-timestampyyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-s-to-a-dateyyyy-mm-dd-h)?

Comment: For a timestamp the data type `timestamp with time zone` is recommended in SQL Your format seems to indicate that in your case `timestamp` without time zone is used? In the latter case pass a modern `LocalDateTime` to your JDBC driver or JPA implementation, and everyone will be happy (except when one day the timestamp is interpreted in the wrong time zone, but preventing that will require changing the table design). See [Dates with no time or timezone component in Java/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285553/dates-with-no-time-or-timezone-component-in-java-mysql).

Comment: (Despite the question title the most upvoted answer under the question I just linked to does treat timestamps with and without time zones.)

Comment: If you indispensably need an old-fashioned `Timestamp` object for a legacy API that you cannot change, get it as `Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT)).toInstant())`. On my Java the resulting `Timestamp` printed as `1996-04-30 02:00:00.0` because my time zone was at UTC offset +02:00 in April 1996.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    ZonedDateTime
    .parse( 
        "Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 UTC 1996" , 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" )
        .withLocale( Locale.US ) 
    ) 
    .toOffsetDateTime()
);
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

In particular, your input data uses a resolution of nanoseconds, while thé `java.util.Date` class is limited to milliseconds.

## ISO 8601

Let me mention that data exchange should be using standard ISO 8601 formats for date-time values transmitted as text. The standard formats are concise, unambiguous, and easily read by both humans and machines.

Use custom or localized formats only for presentation to user, not for storage and data exchange.

So, "Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 UTC 1996" would be `1996-04-30T00:00:00Z` where `Z` is short for `+00:00`, an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

## *java.time*

The *java.time* classes do support the nanoseconds resolution needed for your data inputs.

Define a formatting pattern to match the input. Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in translation.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "IN" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse your input.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( "Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 UTC 1996" , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/NN382a).

> zdt.toString(): 1996-04-30T00:00Z[UTC]

Apparently you want to see this moment as it appears in the India  time zone. Specify the desired time zone as a `ZoneId` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Apply the zone to get another `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/NN382a).

> zdtKolkata.toString(): 1996-04-30T05:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

You asked for a `java.sql.Timestamp` object. That class is one of the terrible legacy classes to avoid. And it is unnecessary. JDBC 4.2 and later requires that a JDBC driver support *java.time*.

To write a moment to a database, we need to use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime`. The SQL standard does not specify time zones, only offsets.

And, there is no need for the India-specific value. Most databases saving into a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` will automatically adjust inputs into UTC (an offset of zero).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

**Beware:** Verify the data type of your database column. If you are using a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, you are using the wrong type. That type **cannot represent a moment**, a specific point on the timeline. Such a type has only a date with time of day, but lacks the context of an offset.